# file path manipulation and archive it dynamically using shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Generated output but it is growing list.

- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/npm/v1/repo/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/atom/v2/repo/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/iterm/v4/repo/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/vscode/v8/repo/*

i have the files generated as above but i need to manipulate it so it can be used following usecase.

****1) Need to move all files from repo to corresponding v* folder (delete repo folder but need to push its contents level up).***

***output need to be like***

- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/npm/v1/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/atom/v2/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/iterm/v4/*
- /mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package/vscode/v8/*

**2) zip each output in seperate files named after its product and another zip with all contents.**

- npm.zip
- atom.zip
- iterm.zip
- vscode.zip
  &&
- package.zip [has all contents in single file]

basic script for task 1

```
for i in `ls -d -1 "$PWD/"**/`
do
cd $i && cd ..
mv repo/* .
rm -rf repo
done
```

it does its work but it looks ugly.

i am trying to get zip files generated based on product name. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First, simplify what you have a bit.

```
for i in "$PWD"/**/; do # this will only be directory names
  cd "$i"/.. && mv repo/* . && rm -rf repo
done
```

but I think we can refine it.

```
base=/mnt/data/workspace/deploy/package
for p in npm atom iterm vscode; do
  cd "$base/$p/" && mv repo/* . && rm -rf repo
done
cd "$base/"
zip package *
for p in npm atom iterm vscode; do zip "$p" "$p/"; done
```

Is that doing what you wanted?